# signalr core & policy based authorization : resource always null

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-authorization

Im using signalr core and its working with role based authorization.

On the other hand my `ClientIdHandler` is working just fine in a test mvc controller with `[Authorize(Policy = "ClientIdPolicy")]`, here is the code of the requirement :

```
public class ClientIdHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ClientIdRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   ClientIdRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!(context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext resource) || resource.HttpContext == null
            || resource.HttpContext.Request == null || resource.HttpContext.Request.Headers == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

        bool success = resource.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ClientId", out var clientIdValue);
        if (!success) return Task.CompletedTask;

        if (!requirement.ClientIds.Contains(clientIdValue.ToString())) return Task.CompletedTask;

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In the mvc controller the policy based authorization is working, but NOT in the signalr hub since `context.Resource` is always `null`.

Is this an issue with signalr or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

it's indeed an issue with signalr as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5279), the solution is to use [IHttpContextAccessor](http://IHttpContextAccessor).

here is the new code of `ClientIdHandler` that worked in both mvc controller and signalr hub:

```
public class ClientIdHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ClientIdRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor = null;

    public ClientIdHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   ClientIdRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (_contextAccessor.HttpContext == null
            || _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request == null || _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

        bool success = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ClientId", out var clientIdValue);
        if (!success) return Task.CompletedTask;

        if (!requirement.ClientIds.Contains(clientIdValue.ToString())) return Task.CompletedTask;

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```